# Get marriage place through a Wikidata SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I'm trying desperately via a sparql query to get some info about Megan Markle's weddings like the location of the wedding, but I can't get it. Could you help me? This is what I tried to do:

```
SELECT ?place
WHERE
{
  wd:Q152316 wdt:P26 [wdt:P2842 ?place].
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wdt:` is used for referring to simple triples. You need prefixes `p:` and `pq:` to access a qualifier.

In your case, the query is the following one:

```
SELECT ?date ?place
WHERE {
  wd:Q152316 p:P26 [
    pq:P580 ?date;
    pq:P2842 ?place
  ] .
}
```

Take a look at [this resource](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SPARQL/WIKIDATA_Qualifiers,_References_and_Ranks) for deepening the topic.

**Extra info**: you can find more data about this marriage in a dedicated item (i.e., [Q43890449](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q43890449), which is accessible through the [P805](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P805) qualifier).

Hence an alternative query is the following one:

```
SELECT ?date ?place
WHERE {
  wd:Q152316 p:P26/pq:P805 ?marriage .
  ?marriage wdt:P585 ?date ;
            wdt:P276 ?place .
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand better how it works.

Comment: How can I write the same query if I don't have a specific item (Q152316) in mind and I want to say obtain the date of marriage for all American actors?

Comment: @FGh You should open a separate question.